# Форма заказа на почту с подсчетом

Tags: php, javascript, phpmailer

> Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть форма заказа на странице с подчетом суммы выбранных `select` и `checkbox`. После заполнения нужных полей отправляется форма на почту с заявкой. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    <h2>Заказать кровать</h2>
<div id="design_parametri">


Стоимость:  <span id="final_price">6300</span>  Руб.
Модель:   <select name="model_krovat" id="model">
     <option value="6300">Белава</option>
     </select>

Ширина:
  <select name="shirina_krovat" id="shirina">

      <option   value="0" selected="selected">800</option>
      <option   value="500">900</option>
      <option   value="1000">1000</option>

    </select>   
<label for="yslygi">Нанесение краски 
<input type="checkbox"  onchange="calc()"  id="yslygi" /> 
<span id="price1">2500</span>   Руб.

function calculate() {
  var sum = 0;

$('select').each(function() {

sum += parseInt($(this).val());
});
var prinprice1 = 0;

//покраска по размерам взяли значения из текста селекта
  if ($("#yslygi").is(':checked'))

{if  (($('#shirina').val() == "0") || ($('#dlina').val() == "0") || ($('#visota').val() == "0")) sum += 2500; prinprice1 += 2500;

  switch ($('#shirina option:selected').text())
  {
    case "900" : sum+=100; prinprice1+=100; break;
    case "1000": sum+=100; prinprice1+=100; break; 
  }
   switch ($('#dlina option:selected').text())
  {
    case "1900" : sum+=100; prinprice1+=100; break;
    case "2000" : sum+=200; prinprice1+=200; break; 

  };
  switch ($('#visota option:selected').text())
  {
    case "1600" : sum+=100; prinprice1+=100; break;
    case "1700" : sum+=200; prinprice1+=200; break; 

  }; 

//вывод на чекбокс покраска
  $('#price1').html(prinprice1); 
} 

//итоговая цена
  $('#final_price').html(sum);

}

$('select,input').change(function() {
  calculate();
});
```

> Код mail.php

```
    $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

//Script Foreach
$c = true;
if ( $method === 'POST' ) {

    $project_name = trim($_POST["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_POST["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_POST["form_subject"]);

    foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
            </tr>
            ";
        }
    }
} else if ( $method === 'GET' ) {

    $project_name = trim($_GET["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_GET["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_GET["form_subject"]);

    foreach ( $_GET as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
            </tr>
            ";
        }
    }
}

$message = "<table style='width: 100%;'>$message</table>";

function adopt($text) {
    return '=?UTF-8?B?'.Base64_encode($text).'?=';
}

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL .
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL .
'From: '.adopt($project_name).' <'.$admin_email.'>' . PHP_EOL .
'Reply-To: '.$admin_email.'' . PHP_EOL;

mail($admin_email, adopt($form_subject), $message, $headers );
```

> На почту приходят вот такие данные
>   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> Нужно в поле напротив Модель было название из `select`,например Белава.
>   В этой же таблице выводилась Общая сумма из `<span id="final_price">6300</span>  Руб.`

Comment: В php не очень разбираюсь, взяла готовый код и скопировала на свои сайт

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Добавила скрипт js:

```
 <script>
function PutToHidden()
{
var hidden;
var select;

select=document.getElementById('select');
hidden=document.getElementById('hidden');

hidden.value=select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
}
```

> в форму дописать `<form  onSubmit='PutToHidden()'>`
>   в коде добавить тег html до select:

```
 <input type='hidden' name='Модель' id='hidden'/>
    <select class="form-control" id="select">
```

> и кнопку переписала:

```
<INPUT style='WIDTH: 200px' type='submit' value='Отправить' name='_submit_' /
```

> Приходит на почту вместе с моделью [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

У Вас в value просто стоимость указана. 
Сделайте скрытое поле при выборе модели и передавайте его из своей формы.

```
<input type='hidden' name'model'>Белава</input>
```

Comment: извините за тупость,эту строчку писать рядом <option value="6300">Белава</option>

Comment: не получается...

Comment: Подскажите,пожалуйста куда эту строчку дописать?<input type=''hidden'' name=''model''>Белава</input>Когда пишу внутри select все съезжается,до и после - не работает.